# Subplot in Julia using Gadfly

Tags: julia

Subplots in Julia using Gadfly

Hi everyone,
I want to create subplot grid in Julia using Gadfly for two different functions/arrays.

For example:
1. `Gadfly.plot(x=rand(20),y=rand(20))`

2. `Gadfly.plot(x=rand(10),y=rand(10))`

The below link shows the example of subplot grid based on DataFrame using Geom.subplot_grid. But I can't find any example for functions/array.
http://gadflyjl.org/v0.6.4/lib/geoms/geom_subplot_grid.html

Can anyone help me out?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Stacks` to achieve what you want.

```
p1 = Gadfly.plot(x=rand(20),y=rand(20))
p2 = Gadfly.plot(x=rand(10),y=rand(10))
stack = hstack(p1, p2) # will arrange the plots horizontally
title(stack, "Horizontally Stacked Plots") # let's give a title
```

You can combine `hstack` and `vstack` to create arbitrary arrangements of plots. Please also take a look at `gridstack` which sometimes makes things easier.  Please refer to [the Stacks section in manual](http://gadflyjl.org/stable/man/compositing/#Stacks-1) to learn more about `Stacks`.